# Linux doesn't (re)detect devices connected to USB hub over USB type C

Tags: usb, dmesg, lsusb

## Problem description

I just bought a new widescreen monitor (Dell Ultrasharp U4919DW) and I use it in split screen mode where one one side my work laptop is connected with DP and on the other side my private laptop (both Lenovo ThinkPad) is connected with USB-C. The monitor also has a built-in USB hub to which I have connected a keyboard and a mouse. The monitor provides a method to switch the peripherals between the laptops (one connected over USB-C, the other over USB 3) and I think this works (and is thus configured right) because at first it works.
However, after I switch to my work laptop (running Windows 10, which works as expected) and then changing back to my private laptop (running Ubuntu), neither the keyboard nor the mouse is detected.

I checked the drivers which should be up to date. However, I am not sure if the correct one is used (see annex).

I looked at the output of `dmesg -w` and it shows that the devices are being disconnected, but never connected again.

If I pull the USB-C cable out of my laptop and plug it in again, it works again as the USB hub is detected once again.

Also, if I `cat /dev/bus/usb/003/001` (the bus of the hub) it detects the devices once again.

I would really like to not have to pull and plug the USB-C cable out and in again, as this gets really cumbersome and destroys the whole experience of having that feature :=)

I hope you can help me with this and just ask for further logs or outputs :)

Notable might also be that both, video and data, run over the same USB-C port (might be a driver issue?).

## Annex:

### `lsusb` output:

When plugged in:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 029: ID 0451:82ff Texas Instruments, Inc.
Bus 003 Device 028: ID 0451:8242 Texas Instruments, Inc.
Bus 003 Device 027: ID 046d:c069 Logitech, Inc. M-U0007 [Corded Mouse M500]
Bus 003 Device 031: ID 413c:2110 Dell Computer Corp.
Bus 003 Device 030: ID 413c:1010 Dell Computer Corp.
Bus 003 Device 026: ID 0451:8442 Texas Instruments, Inc.
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 138a:0097 Validity Sensors, Inc.
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 13d3:5682 IMC Networks
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 1199:9079 Sierra Wireless, Inc.
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 056a:50b8 Wacom Co., Ltd
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

After switching back:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 138a:0097 Validity Sensors, Inc.
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 13d3:5682 IMC Networks
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 1199:9079 Sierra Wireless, Inc.
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 056a:50b8 Wacom Co., Ltd
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

### `dmesg -w` output:

Switching hub:

```
[26612.261206] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 20
[26612.261215] usb 3-2.1: USB disconnect, device number 24
[26612.261220] usb 3-2.1.4: USB disconnect, device number 25
[26612.496703] usb 3-2.2: USB disconnect, device number 21
[26612.555497] usb 3-2.4: USB disconnect, device number 22
[26612.555994] usb 3-2.5: USB disconnect, device number 23
```

Switched agian, nothing happend.
Run `cat /dev/bus/usb/003/001`:

```
[26636.878929] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 26 using xhci_hcd
[26636.899790] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0451, idProduct=8442, bcdDevice= 1.00
[26636.899796] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=1
[26636.899800] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 520100899856
[26636.900723] hub 3-2:1.0: USB hub found
[26636.900761] hub 3-2:1.0: 6 ports detected
[26637.187059] usb 3-2.2: new low-speed USB device number 27 using xhci_hcd
[26637.292037] usb 3-2.2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c069, bcdDevice=56.01
[26637.292044] usb 3-2.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[26637.292048] usb 3-2.2: Product: USB Laser Mouse
[26637.292052] usb 3-2.2: Manufacturer: Logitech
[26637.303877] input: Logitech USB Laser Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:06:00.0/0000:07:02.0/0000:3c:00.0/usb3/3-2/3-2.2/3-2.2:1.0/0003:046D:C069.0064/input/input143
[26637.304366] hid-generic 0003:046D:C069.0064: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Logitech USB Laser Mouse] on usb-0000:3c:00.0-2.2/input0
[26637.383038] usb 3-2.4: new high-speed USB device number 28 using xhci_hcd
[26637.407245] usb 3-2.4: New USB device found, idVendor=0451, idProduct=8242, bcdDevice= 1.00
[26637.407251] usb 3-2.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=1
[26637.407255] usb 3-2.4: SerialNumber: 320108798C82
[26637.408443] hub 3-2.4:1.0: USB hub found
[26637.408511] hub 3-2.4:1.0: 2 ports detected
[26637.487049] usb 3-2.5: new high-speed USB device number 29 using xhci_hcd
[26637.511239] usb 3-2.5: New USB device found, idVendor=0451, idProduct=82ff, bcdDevice= 1.00
[26637.511247] usb 3-2.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=1
[26637.511252] usb 3-2.5: SerialNumber: 520100899856
[26637.514732] hid-generic 0003:0451:82FF.0065: hiddev0,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Device [HID 0451:82ff] on usb-0000:3c:00.0-2.5/input0
[26637.743054] usb 3-2.1: new high-speed USB device number 30 using xhci_hcd
[26637.779756] usb 3-2.1: New USB device found, idVendor=413c, idProduct=1010, bcdDevice=32.98
[26637.779763] usb 3-2.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=11, SerialNumber=0
[26637.779766] usb 3-2.1: Product: USB 2.0 Hub [MTT]
[26637.781487] hub 3-2.1:1.0: USB hub found
[26637.783268] hub 3-2.1:1.0: 4 ports detected
[26638.070958] usb 3-2.1.4: new low-speed USB device number 31 using xhci_hcd
[26638.178914] usb 3-2.1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=413c, idProduct=2110, bcdDevice= 0.06
[26638.178921] usb 3-2.1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[26638.178924] usb 3-2.1.4: Product: Dell Wired Multimedia Keyboard
[26638.178928] usb 3-2.1.4: Manufacturer: Dell
[26638.193018] input: Dell Dell Wired Multimedia Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:06:00.0/0000:07:02.0/0000:3c:00.0/usb3/3-2/3-2.1/3-2.1.4/3-2.1.4:1.0/0003:413C:2110.0066/input/input144
[26638.252082] hid-generic 0003:413C:2110.0066: input,hidraw4: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Dell Dell Wired Multimedia Keyboard] on usb-0000:3c:00.0-2.1.4/input0
[26638.265114] input: Dell Dell Wired Multimedia Keyboard Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:06:00.0/0000:07:02.0/0000:3c:00.0/usb3/3-2/3-2.1/3-2.1.4/3-2.1.4:1.1/0003:413C:2110.0067/input/input145
[26638.265604] input: Dell Dell Wired Multimedia Keyboard System Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:06:00.0/0000:07:02.0/0000:3c:00.0/usb3/3-2/3-2.1/3-2.1.4/3-2.1.4:1.1/0003:413C:2110.0067/input/input146
[26638.323670] input: Dell Dell Wired Multimedia Keyboard Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:06:00.0/0000:07:02.0/0000:3c:00.0/usb3/3-2/3-2.1/3-2.1.4/3-2.1.4:1.1/0003:413C:2110.0067/input/input147
[26638.324373] hid-generic 0003:413C:2110.0067: input,hiddev1,hidraw5: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Dell Dell Wired Multimedia Keyboard] on usb-0000:3c:00.0-2.1.4/input1
```

Comment: `cat /dev/bus/usb/003/001`, wait, you *cat* a device?

Comment: Yeah I just tried and look what happened and it actually triggered some kind of refresh and then it worked...